# Magento 2: what is the catalog_attributes.xml file?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.5

I noticed that Magento 2 contains several `catalog_attributes.xml` files in the following folders:

- `app/code/Magento/Bundle/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Downloadable/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Msrp/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Sales/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Tax/etc`
- `app/code/Magento/Wishlist/etc`

Those files look like this (example for the `Sales` file):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="sku"/>
        <attribute name="type_id"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="status"/>
        <attribute name="visibility"/>
        <attribute name="price"/>
        <attribute name="weight"/>
        <attribute name="url_path"/>
        <attribute name="url_key"/>
        <attribute name="thumbnail"/>
        <attribute name="small_image"/>
        <attribute name="tax_class_id"/>
        <attribute name="special_from_date"/>
        <attribute name="special_to_date"/>
        <attribute name="special_price"/>
        <attribute name="cost"/>
        <attribute name="gift_message_available"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

What are those files used for ?

Comment: see also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-config-node-category-collection-attributes-in-mage

Comment: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/how-to-access-custom-catalog-attributes/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, these files contain a list of attributes that serve different purposes.

The group `used_in_autogeneration` from the file in catalog module serves for listing attributes that have the value autogenerated.
They are retrieved in `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product::getAttributesAllowedForAutogeneration`

The group `quote_item` represents the attributes that are going to be copied from the product to the quote item.

`unassignable` contains the list of attributes that cannot be unassigned from any attribute set.

Sorry, but I don't know all the available groups.

But you are not limited only to the existing groups. You can add your own and use them as you please just by calling `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Config::getAttributeNames('group_name_here')`.  (but instantiate the class first).

**[EDIT]**
I'm not sure about this one, but I think `catalog_category` and `catalog_product` groups hold the system attributes for products and categories.

Answer (score 11):

Just yesterday I stumbled upon that for the first time. It's used for example to add custom attributes to quote item products, otherwise they won't be loaded to save resources (in my case I wanted to display the `color` attribute on the cart page). In Magento 1 you would enter something like this to your module `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <color />
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

To achieve the same in M2, you have to add a `catalog_attributes.xml` to your module and do the following:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="color" />
    </group>
</config>
```