# Magento2 and custom entity options

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, eav

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to `order` entity.

I managed to add a column to `sales_order`, but I cannot save any value while placing the order.

I tracked down the problem in: `Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper::_setDataValues` where my custom column is excluded beacause it is not in the `OrderInterface`.

Is there any way to add it?

How do custom attributes work in Magento 2?

Comment: You may be interested in this answer from a question I asked recently : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/114861/2380

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to work only on product attributes and products related information. I'm trying to add a new attribute to order entity.