# Call to undefined method Mock_AbstractDb_87c49d8f::setStoreId() on getCollection() in Test

Tags: testing, magento-2.1

I am trying to create a test to see if

[What is the equivalent of the config node category/collection/attributes in Magento 2 to add an attribute to the category collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-config-node-category-collection-attributes-in-mage)

works.

I use a integration test (unfinished code)

```
class CatalogAttributesTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $category;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
        $this->category = $objectManager->getObject('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->block = null;
    }

    public function testRedirectUrlAttributeIsThere()
    {
        $this->category->getCollection();
    }
}
```

On test execution I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mock_AbstractDb_87c49d8f::setStoreId() in ..../vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 227
```

Trace

```
PHP  10. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/self/mestrona/workspace/proofgigant.de/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:951
PHP  11. Mestrona\CategoryRedirect\Test\Unit\CatalogAttributesTest->testRedirectUrlAttributeIsThere() /home/self/mestrona/workspace/proofgigant.de/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:951
PHP  12. Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->getCollection() /home/self/mestrona/workspace/proofgigant.de/vendor/mestrona/magento-module-categoryredirect/Test/Integration/CatalogAttributesTest.php:24
PHP  13. Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel->getResourceCollection() /home/self/mestrona/workspace/proofgigant.de/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:517
```

I use the phpunit.xml from `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist` and the database seems to be set up (2 minutes delay when starting up)

It does not seem to use the real integration test database?
What am I doing wrong?

Using the unit/phpunit.xml.dist produced the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I create any category in the `setUp()`

```
protected function setUp()
{
    /**
     * Create category
     * @source \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\FlatTest::testCreateCategory
     */

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
    $category = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category'
    );
    $category->getResource()->load($category, 2);

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryOne */
    $categoryOne = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category'
    );
    $categoryOne->setName('Category ' . uniqid())->setPath($category->getPath())->setIsActive(true);
    $category->getResource()->save($categoryOne);

    $this->category = $categoryOne;
}
```