# Custom Attribute no longer available in the TopMenu since Magento 2.1

Tags: collection, catalog, magento-2.1

In [a Module](https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect) I configured my custom attribute `redirect_url` for categories to be included in the collection using [`catalog_attributes.xml`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-config-node-category-collection-attributes-in-mage)

This seems to no longer work in Magento 2.1

My module defines a plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category`

```
public function aroundGetCategoryUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $subject, \Closure $proceed, $category) {

    if ($category instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
        $redirect = $category->getRedirectUrl();
    } else {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->setData($category->getData());
        $redirect = $category->getRedirectUrl();
    }

    if ($redirect) {
        return $this->_helper->buildUrl($redirect);
    }

    return $proceed($category);
}
```

I have the following integration test:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree
 */
protected $tree;

protected function setUp()
{
    /**
     * Create category
     * @source \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\FlatTest::testCreateCategory
     */

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
    $category = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category'
    );
    $category->getResource()->load($category, 2);

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryOne */
    $categoryOne = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category'
    );
    $categoryOne
        ->setName('Home Category ' . uniqid())->setPath($category->getPath())
        ->setIsActive(true)
        ->setRedirectUrl('/');
    $category->getResource()->save($categoryOne);

    $this->category = $categoryOne;

    $this->tree = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree'
    );
}

public function testAttributeInstalled()
{
    /**
     * @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute
     */
    $attribute = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(
        '\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute'
    );
    $attribute->loadByCode('catalog_category', 'redirect_url');
    $this->assertNotNull($attribute->getId());
}

public function testRedirectUrlAttributeIsInCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->tree->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id' , $this->category->getId());
    $this->assertEquals('/', $collection->getFirstItem()->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

Those tests pass, but the following fails:

```
/**
 * Check if menu items have the right URL
 *
 * @magentoAppArea frontend
 */
public function testUrlInMenu()
{
    \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(
        'Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface'
    )->setDesignTheme(
        'Magento/blank'
    );

    /**
     * @var $layout \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    $layout = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface::class
    );

    $block = $layout->addBlock(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::class, 'test');

    $block->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml');

    $result = $block->toHtml();
    $this->assertContains('http://localhost/index.php/foo-bar', $result);
}
```

Comment: Checking on this.

Comment: Attributes declared in catalog_attributes.xml are used directly by `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree::getCollection` https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Tree.php#L397, This config file doesnt work for collections recived through `MagentoCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category` model. This behavior has no changes since 2.0. You may use direct call to `addAttributeToSelect()` to load required attribute.

Comment: @AntonKaplya But it worked before .. seriously ... the problem is that I need the attribute in an observer so no chance to use addAttributeToSelect. It's for https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect in case you have some time to have a look

Comment: @AntonKaplya Okay, wait a minute ... my test is a bit different from the code not working in the extension - I updated my test case to use the tree collection. Still failing

Comment: @AntonKaplya But my specific test does also not run with 2.0 - but my extension was - so I have to debug further.

Comment: @AntonKaplya Updated my test once again and now it is passing in Mage 2.0 and  Mage 2.1 - so you are basically right

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is, that in catalog 101.0.0 of Magento 2.1 in difference to Magento 2.0's catalog (100.x.x) is, that the category tree is loaded in 
`\Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu::getCategoryTree` which does not use the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree` collection but the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` which does not adhere to `catalog_attributes.xml` as Anton said

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but I just answered to a similar question.
Check if [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187120/54786) answer helps.